# 業務用パッケージアプリケーションのライセンスがライセンスサーバーから取得できない

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

初めまして。初心者で至らない点があると思いますが質問させてください。
また業務のため、詳しく話せない部分もありますがご了承いただければ幸いです。

VM環境で業務用アプリケーションの開発を行っています。
アプリケーションにログインする際、別の場所にあるライセンスサーバーにアクセスしてライセンスを取得する必要があります。
デバッグのため、EclipseからTomcatを実行し、ブラウザからアプリケーションを起動してログインしようとすると、
「ライセンスサーバー上にライセンスが存在しません。」とエラーが出て、アプリケーションにログインできません。

使用環境は
・TMware Workstation 12 Player
・Eclipse Oxygen
・Tomcat 7.0
です。

Windowsのサービス経由でTomcatを起動した場合は、問題なくアプリケーションにログインできます。

現状、サービス経由でTomcatを起動する場合と、Eclipse経由の場合でTomcat実行ユーザーが違っていることを確認しています。
  サービス : Local System account
  Eclipse : VMのログインユーザー

試しにサービスのTomcat実行ユーザーをVMのログインユーザーに変更したところ、Eclipse経由での起動と同じエラーが出ました。

そこで、以下についてご存知の方がいれば、お知恵をお貸しいただきたいです。
・Eclipse経由でのTomcat実行ユーザーを変更する方法があるか
・その他の解決策や心当たりがある(仮説でも構いません)

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://qiita.com/maruq/items/a271490ae39671b07956

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/112079

Comment: 「ライセンスサーバ」はどんな種類かがもし分かれば追記してください（例えばFLEXlmなどがよく使用されます）。また、恐らくライセンスサーバの「ホスト名（またはIPアドレス）」と「ポート番号」を環境変数などで設定しているんじゃないかと思いますが、心当たりはありませんか。

Comment: @cubick さん コメントありがとうございます。調べてみたところ、ライセンスサーバーはパッケージ会社独自のものを使っているみたいで、一般的なものではないようです。 環境変数(ポート番号)は設定したのですが、APサーバーのserver.xmlを調べて、サーバーポート、HTTPポート、AJPポートを同じ通りに設定しているはずなのですが、、

Comment: 「ライセンスサーバー上にライセンスが存在しません。」とエラーを出しているのは、アプリケーションですよね？であれば、まずアプリケーションのログを見て、何も出力されていないようであれば、ログレベルを変えるとか、デバッグしてみるとかした方がいいと思います。